# Irreducibility of a cubic polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+x-1$. Then over which of the following fields $k$ is $f$ irreducible?
>
> 1. $k=\mathbb{Q}$
> 2. $k=\mathbb{R}$
> 3. $k=\mathbb{F}_2$
> 4. $k=\mathbb{F}_3$

**My Attempt:** (2) $f$ is cubic and hence it has a real solution, $\implies$ is not irreducible over $k=\mathbb{R}$

(1) Considering $f'$ and $f''$ and Descartes' Rule of Signs, I concluded that it has only one real root which is positive. Eisenstein Criterion fails. By Rational Root test, if the real root of $f$ is rational, say $\frac{p}{q}$, then $p$ is a factor of $-1$ and $q$ is a factor of $1\implies \frac{p}{q}=1$ (since real root is positive), and since $f(1)\ne0$ we can conclude that it has no rational roots and hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

(3) Over $\mathbb{F}_2$, $f$ is irreducible (since $x,x^2+1,x^2+x+1$ does not divide $f$)

Is it correct so far? And how do I justify for $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Also, though (2) (looks like) it works, I feel I am overkilling it, is there any other way to justify that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: For (2), I would have used the Rational root theorem at the first step, and then you have to check -1 and 1.

Comment: For the sake of precision, your approach to (1) needs to use the fact it has no negative roots. The way you phrased things, it's unclear if you checked that.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I had, anyway, rewrote the line!

Comment: @wythagoras, either way, its just a seconds business when not written!

Comment: For $\Bbb F_2$ and $\Bbb F_3$, you can just check whether $f$ has roots, since it's a third-degree polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\mathbb{Q}$, just go straight to the rational root test: any rational root would have to be $1$ or $-1$, but those aren't roots, since $f(1)=3$ and $f(-1)=-1$.

Similarly, for $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_3$, you can check directly whether there are roots, which suffices for cubic polynomials. Alternatively, for $\mathbb{F}_3$, observe that $$x^3+2x^2+x-1=x^3-x^2+x-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Comment: Thank you! And for $\mathbb{Q}$, is there any other way to prove irreducibility than Rational Root Test?